# Unknown GET request comes automatically after POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

Im tryna submit the simple but for the first time i got this problem .
This the form i working on :

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    <input type="submit" onclick="go()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function go () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            "amount":$("#amount").val(),
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success:function () {
            $('#messages').text("Hey");
        },
        error:function () {
            $('#messages').text("Error");
        }
    });

}


</script>

<li id="messages">

</li>
```

After success the page reload automatically with GET request as in photo:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the submit button does two things:

1. Execute the go() function, which causes the POST-request
2. Submit the form, which causes the GET-request

Not sure what your intentions are, but if you want only to have the POST-request using AJAX, then change the `<input type="submit" ...>` to `<input type="button" ...>`

Comment: I wanna have only the post request .
What should i do ?

Comment: @BaHaaJr. It was not meant as a cliff hanger. I assumed StackOverflow would escape the text. I've edited the answer so that you can see the change in the html.

Comment: your answer is right but in ur opinion why <button> doesn't make a difference

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you mean the difference between <button> and <input type="button">, there isn't much difference. You could change <input type="submit"> to <button> and it will still be fixed. As long as you don't submit the form when pressing the button, the GET-request will disappear.